# Is it safe to clone a git repository into its own .git directory?

Tags: directory-structure, git-clone, git-ftp

I recently put my website under Git version control. I'm using [git-ftp](https://github.com/resmo/git-ftp/) to upload files, and I've set it up so that the `master` branch is the content that *should* be on the server, and the `live` branch is the content that actually *is* on the server. I need to make this distinction since I sometimes develop where I don't have an Internet connection, and therefore can't upload right away. Therefore, in order to upload, I do: `git checkout live;git merge master;git ftp push`; I'd like to automate this process and not lose the rest of working directory state. In the future I'm also going to set up automatic backups of several files which will be ftp'ed down and committed to the `live` branch.

In order to do all of this, I'm going to need another clone that will only be used by automated processes, and will always have a clean working directory. The obvious place to put it, since it will never need to be looked at, is inside the .git directory of the main repository. That way, I don't have a clone floating off somewhere else in my filesystem, it stays hidden, and it's obvious that it's part of the internals and shouldn't be poked about with. If this works well, I may even submit a patch to fix [git-ftp issue #180](https://github.com/resmo/git-ftp/issues/180) with this method.

However, I'm not sure if it's a good idea to put random things inside the .git folder--I can't find any documentation anywhere on what the side effects may be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `.git` directory seems to ignore completely any extra elements, so adding a git repo directly in `.git` should work.
That wouldn't work if you added your nested repo in a sub-directory like, for example, `.git/refs` (see [Git Internals - Git References](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-References))

Note that you could also have that git repo *anywhere in your current git repo*, as a directory named, for instance, `.ftprepo` (a name beginning with a dot, which should be hidden by default)

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer by mistake while looking for something else!

According to https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/#_file_directory_structure, "Higher level SCMs may provide and manage additional information in the $GIT_DIR". This appears to mean that additional info can be stored in .git without causing problems, including, presumably, another clone of the repository.

Comment: And posted before refreshing to check if someone else had already answered. Sorry about that...